# Getting all instances of an object contained in itself

Tags: java

I am not even sure how to really title this. I have a class in Java that creates an instance of itself and stores them in a variable however that instance also creates an instance of itself and stores it in a variable. What I want to do is get all the instances in a list.

I really couldn't come up with a solution. I'm doing something like this:

```java
List<MyClass> myclasses = new ArrayList<>();
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
myclasses.add(myclass);
myclasses.add(myclass.createdinstance);
myclasses.add(myclass.createdinstance.createdinstance);
...
```

It just doesn't make sense to go on forever.

NOTE: it doesn't create these instances infinitely, so it's not like I want to store an infinite amount of MyClasses in there.

Comment: What's the point of this? Sounds like you're trying to build a linked list and keep track of all nodes without going through the list, or it's a [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to do it myself:

```
List<MyClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();
for(MyClass myclass = this; myclass != null; myclass = myclass.anotherinstance) {
    classes.add(myclass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can create a while loop and a buffer variable where you will store the actual instance that you are pushing to the list, then you go with the loop until there is no more nested instances or in other words the property is null. Something like this

```
MyClass buffer = myclass;
while(buffer) {
   myclasses.add(buffer);
   buffer = myclass.createdinstance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function to add the object to the list.

```
void recursiveList(List<Object> myList, Object myObjectWAtrribute) {
    if (myObjectWAtrribute != null && myObjectWAtrribute.getCreatedinstance() != null) {
        myList.add(myObjectWAtrribute.getCreatedinstance());
        recursiveList(myList, myObjectWAtrribute.getCreatedinstance());
    }
}
```

```
List<MyClass> myclasses = new ArrayList<>();
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
// add the first element
myclasses.add(myclass);
// get all subelements
recursiveList(myclasses, myclass);
```